# Some simple questions on directed graphs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I want to know certain properties of directed graphs; in the google books, I am not getting Graph Theory book references, hence posting here my questions.

**(1)** Consider the following graph; while talking about *oriented* cycles in this graph, can we say $2-1-3-4-5-3-2$ is a cycle? (Here vertex $3$ is repeated, but no edge is repeated.) Similarly, in second graph, can we say $2-3-1-2-4-3-2$ is a cycle?

> [image]

**(2)** In directed graphs, I want to see properties of such cycles; what is good reference for this purpose?

Comment: Try to split your question into 3 posts, IMO right now it's too broad (voting to close).

Comment: Something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path ?

Answer (score 2):

Graph theory terminology is quite variable, but the most frequent is to say that cycles are *simple* cycles, that is, no repeated edges or nodes. So both your examples would not constitute cycles in such a sense. You could call them *circuits*.

Answer (score 1):

Both Graph-1 and Graph-2 are NOT considered as cycle digraphs. Rather Graph-1 is known as *$\infty$-digraph*, see reference -  Lin, H. and Shu, J. (2012). A note on the spectral
characterization of strongly connected bicyclic digraphs. Linear Algebra
and its Applications, 436(7):2524--2530.